# Org Mode: Produce Result Block when indirectly calling src block as dependency

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Consider the following org mode document:

```
#+NAME: source
#+BEGIN_SRC python :cache yes
  import random
  return random.randint(3, 300)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS[2314024a531aeb3c9e51cd69e45adf654927e9fa]: source
: 5

#+NAME: source2
#+BEGIN_SRC python :cache yes
  import random
  return random.randint(5, 4000)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: test
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var v=source :var v2=source2
  echo "$v$v2"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test
: 5777
```

If you execute `test` repeatedly as is, `5777` will change each time, just always starting with a 5. This is because `source` has a result block, and it is cached. `source2` does not have a result block, so it is not cached.

If I explicitly then execute `source2`, it will then have a result block and will be cached, so the output of `test` will always be the same.

Is there a way to configure either org mode globally or my source block(s) to produce a `#+RESULT` block even when they are called indirectly, as from executing `test` in this example?

Comment: Good question, but I think the answer is "no". OTOH, you could fairly easily write some code that would evaluate the two python blocks and produce a result, so that *when* you evaluate the third block, they would have cached values. There might be a clever way to automate that, but I haven't gone down that path far enough to say for sure.